# How to replace a row in file (if statment)

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, printwriter

I want to create a file that if a statment is true then give to the line the value '1', if not the value '0'.At the start I'm giving vaue 0 and then if true i have to replace with '1'. This must be inside a for loop and every time check the statment as the code below.

```
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.FileWriter;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.util.logging.Level;
     import java.util.logging.Logger;

     public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            File F=new File("D:\\File.txt");
        try {
        F.createNewFile();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(F));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(F));
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            pw.println(0);
            for ( int j=0;j<10;j++){
               if(i==2)     {   //sample if statment
                   pw.write("1");
                   pw.flush();    }
               if(j==3&&i==3)     {   //sample if statment
                   pw.write("1");
                   pw.flush();    }
                         } 
                  pw.write("\n");
                   }
           pw.close();
           br.close();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
```

Here i have 2 if statments that are true. So the file have to be like that:

```
              0   //0 because i != 2 or i!=3 & j!=3
              0   //0 because i != 2 or i!=3 & j!=3
              1   //1 because i == 2 
              1   //1 because i==3  & j==3
              0   //0 because i != 2 or i!=3 & j1=3
```

Now this that I'm getting from my code is:

```
              0
              0
              0
              11111111110
              10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh, is anything wrong with my question? If i have to change something tell me. Actually i search in Stack Overflow and i couldnt find something like that.

Comment: Note that in your code, zero will be printed first for any value of i. Thats why your result contains 5 zeros. Only inside the j loop, the possibility exists of printing 1's. You should use an if-elseif-else structure inside the j loop and only print zero if neither of the conditions are met. Basically what I mean is that currently, zero will be printed even if the conditions are met.

Comment: It looks good so far except that you don't ask a *particular* question.

Comment: Also, learn to use your IDE's debugger (it is great!). You can then step through your code and see exactly what happens during every iteration of the loops. Maybe use System.out.println to also print to the values to the screen. Question, what IDE do you use to develop in?

Comment: @mdewit I'm using NetBeans 8.2. I try with System.out.println() but still i cant figure it out why the line not being replaced...

Comment: The line wont be replaced. It only adds on to the file. Therefore, you must only write 0 when you really want 0 to permanently be in the file.

Comment: Try this inside your j loop: 
if(i==2) { pw.println(1); } else if (j==3&&i==3) { pw.println(1); } else { pw.println(0);} And remove the  pw.println(0); just below the for(i = 0; i <5 ...) line

Answer (score 0):

When `i==2`, it prints a `0` and a new line (like hitting Enter).

Then it enters the inner loop by `j`, which execute 10 times. Every time because `i` is 2, it prints `1` on the same line. That's why you have the 10 `1`'s.

Then it loops around to get to `i==3`, and prints another `0` and a new line.

Then when the inner loop gets to `j==3` it prints that `1`.

[Edit]
The debugger is your friend!

Comment: ok but how to replace the line every time the contition is true? At the start i give 0 to every line, but the basic idea is to replace that line if its true

Comment: Don't write 0 outright in the beginning. Put it in a variable. Change it to 1 later if the condition is met. Write the variable at the end of each loop.

Answer (score -2):

- why do you execute `pw.println(0);` with *every* iteration of your outer loop?
- what is the difference between `pw.println(0);` and `pw.write("1");`?

Comment: I think this should have been a comment. You are really not offering an answer @Timothy.

Comment: I believe that helping the OP to find the answer herself is more helpful that simple correcting the code.